# Is it gramatically a good start to say "It is definitely not unheard that people say"?

Tags: double-negation

I was reading an answer to a question in this site which started with this phrase:

> It is definitely not unheard that people say ...

I feel it is incorrect or at least not a very nice phrase. Since I'm not a native English speaker, I was wondering what is wrong with this phrase (if there is any)? Can we say it uses a double negative and also a strong affirmative word "definitely" in one sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with the combination of *definitely* followed by *not* and *un . . . .* , but the expression is *unheard **of***, so the sentence would normally occur as

> *It is definitely not unheard of  **for** people **to** say ...*

Comment: A not unblack dog was chasing a not unsmall rabbit...

Answer (score 0):

> It is definitely not unheard that people say ...

The above is a slightly-distorted (and incorrect) version of

> It is definitely not unheard for people to say ...

which in effect means

> People have been heard to say...

Answer (score 0):

This (*It is definitely not unheard that people say*) is **not** a double negative, which is inherently ungrammatical in standard English (but not in all of its dialects). However,  this particular phrase is both ungrammatical (the idiomatic expression *not unheard of* is incomplete) and poor style (*definitely* gives unnecessary emphasis). It should be:

> It is not unheard **of** {for people to say / that people say} X.

or

> Some people say X.

But we can cut non-native speakers some slack. We don't need to criticize everything that everyone says, regardless of their level of fluency in English. If the answer is understandable, all that needs to be done is to edit the answer to correct the grammar. Non-native speakers who answer questions about English are brave and I applaud them, except when they give incorrect and unhelpful information. Sometimes native speakers are guilty of the same thing. People make mistakes, so we have to be flexible, kind, and understanding, not nasty or overly critical (IMHO).

Comment: While I agree with everything else in your answer, I wouldn't agree that the emphasis that "definitely" gives in the sentence is unnecessary, especially if you want to stress that something is in common use. To me, "It's not unheard of..." suggests that something is quite rare, whereas "It's definitely not unheard of..." suggests that it is more common.

Comment: @Matt: If the answer is responding to an assertion that it is {certainly / definitely / undoubtedly} unheard of, then I agree that _definitely_ is an appropriate word, but if it's just a simple response to a simple Q, eg, "Is it unheard of that people say X?", then I think it's too strong. Saying simply that "[It] is in common use" should be emphatic enough.